# What does "_*" mean when used after array?

Tags: scala

I have been working on some scala code and I have faced `_*` used after the arrays like the following (`args: _*`).

Can someone tell me its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function that takes a variable number of arguments, like:

```
def print(args: String*) {
  elements.foreach(println)
}
```

You can call this with multiple parameters:

```
print("a")
print("a","b")
```

Or if you have a sequence, you can call it with a list, but in this case you need to use the _* syntax to splat the sequence instead of passing it as a single parameter

```
val l = List("a","b")
print(l: _*)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

As per the scala documentation this means vararg expansion.
[other symbols](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html)

Vararg in Java was added in java 1.5 so that it can be utilized when the number of parameters to a method are not known.

Some important points about vararg:
- Anonymous array is created every time a method is called, which increases the time complexity. So in case when method call results in 1 or 2 parameter most of the time then prefer overloading rather than using vararg.